# How to implement ML Kit Firebase on React Native app?

Tags: firebase, react-native, firebase-mlkit

I am trying to build a simple app that takes a picture of a dog, and it tells me what breed of dog it is. I got the camera working on my reactnative app, and uploaded my custom TFlite model to my project on Firebase. Im not sure how to proceed as my next step. The Firebase ML documentation suggests that I can only do so with native code (ios/android) My next step is 'sending' the picture i took to the custom model on Firebase. Is this possible, if so, how? thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can try this PR for ML Kit wrapper which adds support for image labeling https://github.com/a7medev/react-native-ml-kit/pull/21